# jQuery element prefix selector

Tags: jquery

Can a jQuery selector be used to find elements that begin with a certain prefix? For example, I would like to select all elements that start with the `my:` prefix in the following snippet of HTML:

```
<div>
    <my:Textbox id="..." />
    <my:FancyList ... />
</div>
```

Comment: dumb question here, don't the custom pre-fixes get converted to something else after rendering by the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter

```js
var myElements = $('*').filter(function() {
  return /^MY\:/.test(this.tagName);
});

console.log(myElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <my:Textbox id="..." />
  <my:FancyList ... />
</div>
```

Note that `tagName` returns the name in uppercase form

Comment: You should probably also include the colon `:` in your regex.